# How can I see the list of users..?

Tags: users, user-management

I'm fresh to Linux , to be precise this is the first day I'm sitting before Ubuntu OS.
I added users for a learning purpose & now I want to see all the users in the system. How do I see the users ? If there is more than 1 way, kindly let me know all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Failsafe way

They are listed in `/etc/passwd`. However, this will include "system" users. Generally, "normal" users start with a UID of 1000, so you can filter these out with.

```
awk -F ':' '$3>999' /etc/passwd
```

N.B. that I also have a user called "nobody" with UID 65534, so there are some false positives.

#### Explanation of code

- `awk -F ':'` use `awk` with field seperator of `:`.
- `'$3>999'` only print line if the third field is greater than 999.
- `/etc/passwd` read from this file.

## Easier way

Most users will have a directory in home. N.B. this may not work if a user doesn't have this directory.

```
ls /home
```

(Also, ignore `lost+found` if it exists, as it's not associated with a user.)

Comment: Both are excellent, however please be aware that the two methods can give different results, because UIDs and GIDs used for home folders can differ from those specified in the `/etc/passwd` file, e.g. by sharing the same UID across some users home folders (or even all in case of  NFS).

Answer (score 0):

`getent passwd`

This method has the advantage of listing both users that are defined on this system (i.e. listed in `/etc/passwd`) and users that may be brought in via a single sign-on method, e.g. LDAP users.

If you only want to see the non-system users:

`getent passwd | awk -F ':' '$3>999' | grep -v nobody`